# WifiDirect: Sometimes DnsSdServiceResponseListener callback never called by system

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct, wifip2p

This is base useage of     `DnsSdServiceResponseListener`

```
    WifiP2pManager manager = (WifiP2pManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    WifiP2pManager.Channel channel = manager.initialize(context, context.getMainLooper(), null);

    manager.setDnsSdResponseListeners(channel, new WifiP2pManager.DnsSdServiceResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDnsSdServiceAvailable(String instanceName, String registrationType, WifiP2pDevice srcDevice) {
            Log.d("OK" , "called"); 
        }
    }, null);
```

In this callback WifiConnection with group owner is started

Q: Why method `onDnsSdServiceAvailable` may be never called? It's a floating bug, that I couldn't catch and describe what it causes.
To make it working again I have to reboot Wifi manually

Answer (score 0):

The DnsSdServiceResponseListener will be called when the WiFiP2PManager discovers a service instance. So after adding it to the manager object, make sure to start discovering services.

```
manager.discoverServices(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Success!
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int code) {
            // Command failed.  Check for P2P_UNSUPPORTED, ERROR, or BUSY
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.